# Rwanda Visa Application, Supporting Documents?

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens, rwanda

Ok i am nigerian, I want to know what supporting document i should use when Submitting a Visa Application for Rwanda. I have been asking around and I basically do not have anyone to advise on the actual documents in this case.

Please I Sure do need clarification of some sort.

Thanks

Comment: Where have you searched for information up until now?

Comment: Is there a written or online application form? What information is asked for?

Comment: What is the purpose of your trip? Supporting documents vary depending on whether it is a business trip, tourism, a social visit, or whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

Rwanda issues visas on arrival. See https://www.migration.gov.rw/our-services/visa/

Requirements listed on that page are:
- travel document
- vaccination certificate may be required, although it doesn't mention for which disease(s)
- fees, amounts not specified
- evidence of sufficient funds